# Django: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am getting this error, and it seem to be a problem with the router

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from main import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'login', LoginView.as_view(), basename='login')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(router.urls()))


]
```

error:

```
extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

here is the full traceback, stackoverflow could not let me post a full trackback because of formatting issue:

https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/620b2e1923014f3c8ae2eec788656d7b

so I assume the view have no problems (which is Django default view), anyone can help me solve the issue?

Comment: Don't call `router.urls()`, just include them as they are by removing the parenthesis - `include(router.urls)`

Comment: @IainShelvington i still get the same error

Comment: You're trying to register a normal non-restframework view in a router, why? The routers are expecting viewsets

Comment: What do you suggest ? @IainShelvington

Comment: Not doing that. Just use the normal Django url functions for that view and save the routers for when you use rest framework viewsets

Comment: post your comment as answer so i can approve it, you are a savior.